# access shadowed global variable in C via dlsym not work

Tags: c++, c, linux

```
int myvar=100;

main()
{
  pid_t (*f) (void );
  int *ip;
  int myvar=10;

  f = (pid_t(*) (void)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpid");
  ip = (int *) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "errno");
  if (ip) 
    printf("%d \r\n", *ip);
  ip = (int *) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "myvar");
  if (ip) 
    printf("%d \r\n", *ip);  //not work where is i am wrong
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more description to this question?  What problem are you having?  What have you tried?  What are you trying to do?  Context makes it much easier to answer the question.

Comment: Casting `dlsym` is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myvar` will not be generally exported into the dynamic symbol table, unless you use a linker flag like `-rdynamic` when linking it.

Comment: it not get memery location useing RTLD_NEXT but give when RTLD_DEFAULT why i can't understand it

Answer (score 2):

The `getpid` and `errno` symbols are exported by the libc.
`myvvar` symbols is in your executable and is probably not exported.

Objdump -T will help you to check if the symbol is exported or not.

```
$ objdump -T /lib/libc.so.6 | grep -w getpid
00c9c570 g    DF .text  00000036  GLIBC_2.0   getpid
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the C++ scope operator:

```
::myvar = myvar + 1;
```

and then namespaces.